# How could I speed up this exporting data function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have a feature for users to be able to export the database information. But if the user choose all options to export it takes 1 minute or more to download the .csv file. I'm only including 1 part of the if statement, where I'm pulling in all the data.

here it is:

```
  function exportTheData() {
        //get the data for data array
        if(exportVolumeData == 1) {

            for(j=0; j<plantData1.length; j++) {

                i = plantData["MergeKey_lvl00"].indexOf(plantData1["MergeKey_lvl00"][j]);

                data.push(plantData["PlantName"][i]);

                if(statesExport == 1) {
                    countyindex = counties["CountyId"].indexOf(plantData["LocationId"][i]);
                    stateid = counties["StateId"][countyindex];
                    statename = states["StateName"][states["StateId"].indexOf(stateid)];

                    data.push(statename);
                }
                if(countyExport == 1) {
                    countyindex = counties["CountyId"].indexOf(plantData["LocationId"][i]);
                    countyname = counties["CountyName"][countyindex];

                    data.push(countyname);
                }
                if(basinsExport == 1) {
                    countyindex = counties["CountyId"].indexOf(plantData["LocationId"][i]);
                    subbasinid = counties["SubBasinId"][countyindex];
                    subbasinindex = basinSub["SubBasinId"].indexOf(subbasinid);
                    basinid = basinSub["BasinId"][subbasinindex];
                    basinindex = basin["BasinId"].indexOf(basinid);
                    basinname = basin["BasinName"][basinindex];

                    data.push(basinname);
                }           
                if(subBasinsExport == 1) {
                    countyindex = counties["CountyId"].indexOf(plantData["LocationId"][i]);
                    subbasinid = counties["SubBasinId"][countyindex];
                    subbasinindex = basinSub["SubBasinId"].indexOf(subbasinid);
                    subbasinname = basinSub["SubBasinName"][subbasinindex];

                    data.push(subbasinname);
                }           
                if(paddsExport == 1) {
                    countyindex = counties["CountyId"].indexOf(plantData["LocationId"][i]);
                    subpaddid = counties["SubPaddId"][countyindex];
                    subpaddindex = paddSub["SubPaddId"].indexOf(subpaddid);
                    paddid = paddSub["PaddId"][subpaddindex];
                    paddindex = padd["PaddId"].indexOf(paddid);
                    paddname = padd["PaddName"][paddindex];

                    data.push(paddname);
                }           
                if(subPaddsExport == 1) {
                    countyindex = counties["CountyId"].indexOf(plantData["LocationId"][i]);
                    subpaddid = counties["SubPaddId"][countyindex];
                    subpaddname = paddSub["SubPaddName"][paddSub["SubPaddId"].indexOf(subpaddid)];

                    data.push(subpaddname);
                }           
                if(fullNameExport == 1) {
                    companyindex = getCompanyInfo["MergeKey_lvl00"].indexOf(plantData["OperatorId"][i]);
                    fullname = getCompanyInfo["FullName"][companyindex];

                    data.push(fullname);
                }           
                if(shortNameExport == 1) {
                    companyindex = getCompanyInfo["MergeKey_lvl00"].indexOf(plantData["OperatorId"][i]);
                    shortname = getCompanyInfo["ShortName"][companyindex];

                    data.push(shortname);
                }           
                if(tickerExport == 1) {
                    companyindex = getCompanyInfo["MergeKey_lvl00"].indexOf(plantData["OperatorId"][i]);
                    ticker = getCompanyInfo["Ticker"][companyindex];

                    data.push(ticker);
                }

                volumeindex = plantData1["MergeKey_lvl00"].indexOf(plantData["MergeKey_lvl00"][i]);
                startdate = plantData1["MonthStartDate"][volumeindex];
                volumetypeindex = plantData2["VolumeTypeId"].indexOf(plantData1["VolumeTypeId"][j]);
                volumetype = plantData2["VolumeType"][volumetypeindex];
                volumeunit = plantData2["Unit"][volumetypeindex];
                volume = plantData1["Volume"][volumeindex];

                data.push(startdate);
                data.push(volumetype);
                data.push(volumeunit);
                data.push(volume);
            }

        /* * Convert our data to CSV string */
        var CSVString = prepCSVRow(titles, titles.length, '');
        CSVString = prepCSVRow(data, titles.length, CSVString);
        /* * Make CSV downloadable*/
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", CSVString]);
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.href = url;
        downloadLink.download = "data.csv";
        /** Actually download CSV */
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
   }
```

Here is where I convert the data array to csv string:

```
        function prepCSVRow(arr, columnCount, initial) {
      var row = ''; // this will hold data
      var delimeter = ','; // data slice separator, in excel it's `;`, in usual CSv it's `,`
      var newLine = '\r\n'; // newline separator for CSV row
    /* * Convert [1,2,3,4] into [[1,2], [3,4]] while count is 2
       * @param _arr {Array} - the actual array to split
       * @param _count {Number} - the amount to split
       * return {Array} - splitted array */
      function splitArray(_arr, _count) {
        var splitted = [];
        var result = [];
        _arr.forEach(function(item, idx) {
          if ((idx + 1) % _count === 0) {
            splitted.push('"' + item + '"');
            result.push(splitted);
            splitted = [];
          } else {
            splitted.push('"' + item + '"');
          }
        });
        return result;
      }
      var plainArr = splitArray(arr, columnCount);
      // don't know how to explain this
      // you just have to like follow the code
      // and you understand, it's pretty simple
      // it converts `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `a,b,c` string
      plainArr.forEach(function(arrItem) {
        arrItem.forEach(function(item, idx) {
          row += item + ((idx + 1) === arrItem.length ? '' : delimeter);
        });
        row += newLine;
      });
      return initial + row;
    }
```

Any idea on how I could speed this up? We have over 6,000 rows of data in the database. Thanks!

Comment: http://papaparse.com/

Comment: Consider using promises (*async js*)? Or multi-processing with [Node-cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Comment: Have you tried http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I have not tried codereview but I will thanks!

Comment: I just created a question on codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160138/how-could-i-speed-up-this-exporting-data-function-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the data.push.. to data[data.length] = .. has made the function a lot faster. Also, I created variables for countyindex and companyindex instead of calling it multiple times in the same function.

Also, cleaning up the last part of the function really helped:

```
  /* * Convert our data to CSV string */
 var CSVString = prepCSVRow(titles, titles.length);
 CSVString += prepCSVRow(data, titles.length);

 /* * Make CSV downloadable*/
 var downloadLink = document.createElement('a'),
  blob         = new Blob(['\ufeff', CSVString]);

 downloadLink.href     = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 downloadLink.download = 'data.csv';

 /** Actually download CSV */
 document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 downloadLink.click();
 document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```